# Heroku app is pointing at the incorrect heroku url

Tags: heroku, dns, cname

I'm adding an SSL cert to a heroku app. There's a DNS check that is showing the following:

[image]

The issue is that the first CNAME record points to a heroku app that no longer exists.
When I check `host www.myapp.com` via the terminal it also lists the wrong heroku app and says that it is an alias of the custom domain.

How do I delete the incorrect heroku app url from the app?
I've added the CNAME record to point to the herokudns.com url but it makes no difference.
Is there somewhere inside the heroku dashboard or in my own code where I can make a change that will disentangle this incorrect url from my app?

Comment: This doesn't sounds like it has anything to do with Heroku. It's a DNS issue, so you'll have to fix it wherever you configure your DNS records.

Comment: It's just so strange that a CNAME that doesn't exist is showing up...I do think it's n the DNS side. Just not sure where it's coming from.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "doesn't exist". Did you remove the relevant DNS record? Deleting the Heroku app doesn't affect DNS at all.

Comment: From the DNS control panel where I can add CNAME records there is not a CNAME that references the CNAME record I see when running "host www.myapp.com" in the terminal.  So, it shouldn't exist...but it does.

Comment: How long ago did you delete that record? DNS takes time to propagate.

Comment: Is there a way to verify where the CNAME is set? ie lookup the domain and it will tell you GoDaddy etc? Reason being is I did not recently delete the CNAME that shouldn't exist so I'm wondering if my client is mistaken about where the records should be edited.

Comment: I got it working! The client was telling me the wrong place to set DNS records. I found the odd CNAME at another host. I've deleted it and everything is working! Appreciate your ideas.